# Displaying multiple rows from a MySQL table with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table called "contests" which holds contests created by users.
Each row has 5 columns: id, title, description, instructions and username.
ID is the id of the contest which will be used in the permalink, title will be shown on the contest page and the user's "my contests" page, instructions will be shown on the contest page and the username will be shown on the contest page. I use it to determine who created each contest.

I'm having trouble displaying all the user's contests in his/her "My Contests" page. It gives me this error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 110
>   1
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 111
>   1
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 110
>   1
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 111
>   1
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 110
>   T
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 111
>   T
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 110
>   T
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 111
>   T
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 110
>   t
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 111
>   t
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 110
>   t
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 111
>   t
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 110
>   d
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 111
>   d
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 110
>   d
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 111
>   d
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 110
>   C
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 111
>   C
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 109 C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 110 
>   C
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'description' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpcontests\i\my-contests.php on line 111 
>   C

My code:

```
        <?php
    $table = $config['mysql']['contest_table'];
    $query = $db->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE username=:username");
    $query->bindValue(':username', $_SESSION['username']);
    if($query->execute()) {
        $rows = $query->fetch();
        if(count($rows) > 0) {
            foreach($rows as $row) {
                echo "<h3><a href='contests.php?id=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['title'] . "</a></h3>";
                echo "<p>" . $row['end_date'] . "</p>";
                echo "<p>" . $row['description'] . "</p>";
                echo "<br />";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<p>You haven't created any contests yet. <a href='create.php'>Create one now</a>.</p>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

This is my first time using PDO - I just made the leap from mysql_* functions.

Edit: I updated my code and the errors are now gone. It only displays information about the second contest though.

`<?php
        $table = $config['mysql']['contest_table'];
        $query = $db->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE username=:username");
        $query->bindValue(':username', $_SESSION['username']);
        if($query->execute()) {
            $rows = $query->fetchAll();
            var_dump($rows);
            if(count($rows) > 0) {
                foreach($rows as $row) {
                    echo "<h3><a href='contests.php?id=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['title'] . "</a></h3>";
                    echo "<p>" . $row['end_date'] . "</p>";
                    echo "<p>" . $row['description'] . "</p>";
                    echo "<br />";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<p>You haven't created any contests yet. <a href='create.php'>Create one now</a>.</p>";
            }
        }
        ?>`

Comment: Preparing table names in queries is not allowed.

Comment: You cannot bind the tablename with pdo

Comment: Ahh, ok. I replaced it with a variable and updated the post. I get a new batch of warnings now.

Comment: `var_dump($row)` and see it's content

Comment: `string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(12) "Test Title 1" string(12) "Test Title 1" string(18) "Test Description 1" string(18) "Test Description 1" string(19) "Test Instructions 1" string(19) "Test Instructions 1" string(8) "Coolpool" string(8) "Coolpool"` <- Seems to only show the first row and is duplicating the columns for some reason; I made two example contests.

Comment: Please read `fetch` manual - http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Changed it to fetchAll(). It now removes all errors but only shows the 2nd contest's information.

Answer (score 0):

fetch should be use in a while loop, like this

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 //..
}
```

if you wanted to use a foreach loop use `fetchAll()`

```
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row) {
//...
}
```

That's because `fetch()` get one record at the time, while `fetchAll()` gets it all at one time.
So using `fetch()` the cursor needs moves a row at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I changed it to `fetchAll()` and that got rid of the errors, but it only displays information for the second contest.

Comment: @WillMacklemore  it sound like you fetch twice, make sure you fetch only once, show your update code as weell

Comment: @WillMacklemore `foreach($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {..}`

Comment: It says I don't have any contests now & var_dump is `array(0) { }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55014/discussion-between-meda-and-will-macklemore).

Answer (score -1):

in your foreach use `$rows['id']` etc this wil help you to get rid of the  "Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in" warning